# OS X: library not found for -licudata

Tags: macos, boost, linker, linker-errors

I'm trying to build a C++ project that I originally developed for Linux on `MAC OS X 10.15.7`. During linking, a dependency (I believe Boost) requires the `-licudata` flag. This leads to a "library not found" error. So far I have not been able to figure out how to resolve this, I have installed `boost@1.75` via brew but that is seemingly not enough.

Comment: Nothing to do with Boost it seems. iCU data library ? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37842/libicudata-3lib.html

Comment: @PaulR: I think that is a dependency of Boost Regex, at least it doesn't show up anymore when I don't link against Boost.

Comment: `brew install icu4c` ?

Comment: @PaulR: Sadly not. My development process is a little slow, I don't actually have access to a macOS installation, I'm trying to do this via GitHub Actions. That makes figuring this out a bit painful.

Comment: I just checked my Mac installation here and libicu is installed under /usr/local by homebrew, so it's evidently not part of the default macOS libraries and you'll need to either install it via homebrew or some other means.

Comment: @PaulR: Seems like the boost formula is broken then? Or maybe this is a problem with my CMake code but I don't see how, since I never explicitly reference libicudata anywhere.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that perhaps Unicode support in the relevant boost library might be optional, and that disabling it might remove the dependency ? Just a wild guess though.

Comment: @PaulR: Apparently you can install `boost --with-icu4c` but I'm _not_ doing that so the dependency should not be there.

Comment: @PaulR I have found `libicudata*` under `/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib` but even symlinking that to `/usr/local/lib` doesn't solve it, which is... strange.

Comment: You might need to add /usr/local/lib to the library search paths - it used to be included by default in older versions of clang but I think Apple removed it from the config at some point.

Comment: @PaulR: I have directly added /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib to the search path. It links, but... on execution I get: `Library not loaded: @loader_path/libicuuc.67.dylib`. All of this just seems fundamentally wrong.

Comment: That suggests that DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH needs updating, but as you say, this all seems “wrong”. I don’t have any further suggestions I’m afraid - you may need to get access to a Mac to investigate further,

Comment: I think there's something wrong in the Boost 1.75.0 package, since I don't see any difference in the dependencies of Boost::Regex between 1.74 and 1.75. Then why now it needs `libicudata.dylib` under `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: @AlvaroPalmaAste I tried to look into it but unfortunately i don't quite understand how homebrew works internally or what the root of the problem is.

Comment: There's an issue created for Homebrew regarding this matter: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/67427 and also https://github.com/boostorg/boost_install/issues/47

Comment: set `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` to `off` works for me  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/67427#issuecomment-754141236